# how to select parameter for tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am now doing a DNN regression analysis. I use the tensflow's DNNRegressor. But I don't know how to adjust the appropriate parameters to get a good neural network model?

```
regressor = tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_cols,
            # hidden_units=[10, 128],  # loss:42.252525
            # hidden_units=[50, 320],  # 7.66
            # hidden_units=[50, 640],  # 22.162941
            # hidden_units=[100, 640], # 5.249118
            # hidden_units=[100, 320], # 6.54
            # hidden_units=[300, 640], # 41.01174
            # hidden_units=[300, 896], # 17.183

            # hidden_units=[50, 100, 640], # 17.760363
            # hidden_units=[50, 320, 640], # 16.38122
            # hidden_units=[50, 320, 128, 50], # 52.36839
            # hidden_units=[640, 100], # 53
            hidden_units=[100, 320, 640],  # 22.162941

            model_dir='./models/dnnregressor',
            weight_column_name = None,
            optimizer=None,
            activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
            dropout=None,
            gradient_clip_norm=None,
            enable_centered_bias=False,
            config=config,
            feature_engineering_fn=None,
            label_dimension = 4,
            embedding_lr_multipliers=None,
            input_layer_min_slice_size=None)
```

My dataset looks like this.

```
df = conv2_dataframe(CmdS_X=CmdS_X, CmdS_Y=CmdS_Y, CmdS_Z=CmdS_Z, CmdV=CmdV, halfV=halfV,
       ActS_X=ActS_X, ActS_Y=ActS_Y, ActS_Z=ActS_Z, ActV=ActV)
labels = ['ActS_X', 'ActS_Y', 'ActS_Z', 'ActV']

dnnRegressor(df, labels)
```

shape: (12686, 9)
[Data description diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6y7k.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple answer. It depends on your data characteristics and exact problem. This problem is generally referred to as "hyper-parameter tuning".

If you want a short answer - do a proper training, validation, and test dataset split and use whatever parameters give best results on your test dataset.